# Gatsby Develop: cannot destructure property `frontmatter` of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm new to Gatsby and GraphQL. I was trying to build a blog-like website. I'm using a template for the blog post page which leads to the use of gatsby-node.js and I think this is causing the issue. It runs fine in development mode but as I try to build it, it gives me an error. I'm on the latest version of everything.

Command: **Gatsby build**

Error: 
[image]

Also, here are my files attached.

**gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter, ...props }) => {
  console.log(actions, graphql, reporter, props)
  const { createPage } = actions
  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve(`src/pages/lead-generation.js`)
  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(limit: 1000) {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              path
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  // Handle errors
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }
  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.frontmatter.path,
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      context: {}, // additional data can be passed via context
    })
  })
}
```

**lead-generation.js**

```
export default class Template extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { markdownRemark: { frontmatter = {}, html } = {} } =
      this.props.data;

    return (
      <div className="p-3">
        <div>
          <h1>{frontmatter.title}</h1>
          <h6 className="pb-5">{frontmatter.articleHeading}</h6>
          <div
            className="blog-post-content"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }}
          />
        </div>
        <div
          id="container"
          className="p-5"
          style={{ height: 500, width: 400 }}
        >
          {/* widget*/}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
        articleHeading
        categoryID
      }
    }
  }
`
```

**markdown-file.md**

```
---
path: "/works/remaining-URL"
title: "some title?"
articleHeading: "This is some heading"
categoryID: 10056
---

This is the further text
```

I have simplified the question out. Please let me know if you need further elaboration.

Comment: Hi! Please reduce the example to the [minimum necessary](/help/mcve). Also note that the line quoted in the error is **not** the same as the line in the code you've posted; the error line has a `|| {}` that the code in the question doesn't. Assuming you do have that `|| {}`, I can't see that error occurring, as the destructuring is just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/6amyech0/

Comment: Hi, thank you for replaying Yes, I removed that as I was trying to de-structure in a different way. The problem is not with de-structuring I have verified that and the code is working fine in development mode. It is only happening when I try to build.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to report to Webpack.

Comment: Can you `console.log(blogPostTemplate)` from your `gatsby-node.js`?

Comment: Okay, so this is something really strange that I just noticed. Even it throw an error but the build generated is working very fine. @awran5 these logs are fine. But the issue seems something else.

Comment: `query($path: String!)` in `lead-generation.js` is looking for a variable named `path` on the page context, but there isn't one.